# What extra conditions are needed to state $f = g, \mu-$a.e. if $\int_{X}fd\mu=\int_{X}gd\mu$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I am aware that:

$g = f, \mu-$a.e. $\Rightarrow \int_{X}fd\mu=\int_{X}gd\mu$

But I am interested in the conditions need to state that

$\int_{X}fd\mu=\int_{X}gd\mu\Rightarrow f = g, \mu-$a.e.

Do such conditions exist at all?

Comment: If $\mu$ is a measure on $X$ and $f,g:X\to\mathbb{R}$ are $\mu$-measurable, then if $f\ge g$ (or $g\ge f$) on $X$, you can conclude that $f=g$ almost everywhere. (It's the same as asking a different question: if $h$ is $\mu$-measurable and $\int_X h d\mu = 0$, is it true that $h=0$ almost everywhere? We use $h=f-g$ in our case. As soon as you allow $h$ to have opposite signs on positive-measure sets, you're out of luck.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably after the following theorem.

**Theorem.** For two *integrable* functions $f, g:\mathrm{X} \to \bar{\mathbf{R}} =[-\infty, \infty]$ to be equal for almost every point of $\mathrm{X},$ it is necessary and sufficient that for every measurable subset $\mathrm{A}$ of $\mathrm{X}$ the two integrals coincide $\int\limits_\mathrm{A} f = \int\limits_\mathrm{A} g.$

*Proof.* You probably already know the necessity, as for the sufficency consider $\mathrm{A}_n = \{f > g + \frac{1}{n}\}$ and $\mathrm{B}_n = \{f + \frac{1}{n} < g\}.$ Is easy to see each of these measurable sets has measure zero, hence so their union and thus, $f = g$ for almost every point, as was to be shown.

Answer (score 1):

For two integrable functions $f,g$ on $X = \mathbb{R}^n$, if you know not only that $\int_X f d\mu = \int_X g d\mu$, but also $\int_Q f d\mu = \int_Q g d \mu$ for every cube $Q = [a_1,b_1] \times ... \times [a_n,b_n] \subset X$, then you can conclude that $f = g$ almost everywhere. This is proven by seeing that this is property is equivalent to $f-g$ being orthogonal to indicator functions of all cubes in the $L^2$-scalar product, and with arguments about the density of the linear span of indicator functions, one can then deduce that this means $f-g$ must be zero almost everywhere. (There are some details to be filled in, but in general, that should be the idea.)

EDIT: In fact, a result like that holds, by a more general, measure-theoretic proof, even on arbitrary measure spaces, see [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/630029/question-of-lebesgue-integrals-to-show-functions-are-the-same-mu-a-e?rq=1) Had not thought of that at first.

Of course, that is a much stronger requirement than what you started with, but what you started with is pretty weak to begin with :) It is like asking "If two shapes have the same area, what are the conditions that they are identical?", which as you can imagine, has a boatload of different answers.